# How to delete The array item in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Code:-.

Parent component

```
const LeftNav = () => {
return (

            <div className="allDivs">
                {item.map((items, index) => {
                    //   console.log(item)

                    return (
                        <div key={index} >
                            <TabHeader item={items} index={index} DeleteItemlist={item}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

 </div >
    )
}
export default LeftNav;
```

Child componentL;-

```
export default function TabHeader({ item, index }) {


const handleToggle = useCallback((e, ID, channelName) => {
        DeleteItemlist(itemList.filter(item => item.val !== channelName));
    }, [])
return (
        <Fragment>
            <div id="CLOSEDIV">
                <div className="TableText" onClick={(e) => { handleOnClick(e, Delete.val) }}>
                    <div id="SHOW">{Delete.val}</div>
                </div>
<div className="CloseIcon" id="CloseBtn"><FaRegTimesCircle
                    style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "20px", height: "20px", alignItems: "right" }}
                    onClick={(e) => { handleToggle(e, index, Delete.val) }} /></div>
            </div>
</div>
 </Fragment >

    )
}
```

its working fine when there is only one div but when there is more than 1 div they close all the div
how can i close 1 div at a one time?

please help..

Comment: Probably not related, but worth fixing either way: You are creating duplicate IDs for `SHOW` and `CloseBtn` when you add multiple `TabHeader` components. I would suggest avoiding using IDs entirely unless they are absolutely necessary (And if they are, I would add some randomness/GUID generating logic to avoid collisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confusing and hard to read and your question is also a little bit unclear and confusing (the title says **delete** while you're asking "how can I **close** one div at a time"). I assume that you want to delete your child item from your parent component.

You could achieve that by passing a callback as a prop to the child component.   Here's an example of what I mean exactly:

```js
const MyItem = ({ item, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: "8px" }}>
      <span>{item.val} </span>
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(item.val)}>Delete item</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);

  const onDelete = (val) => {
    setItems((old) => old.filter((d) => d.val !== val));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((x, index) => (
        <MyItem key={index} item={x} onDelete={onDelete} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's the Codesandbox link of the full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-firefly-5gpo01?file=/src/App.js)